# I am facing error("invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value") on registering admin user in ejabberd via command?

Tags: docker, ejabberd

Below is the command I am executing

```
docker exec -it 97e6a996ccd1 bin/ejabberdapi register --endpoint=http://127.0.0.1:5280 --jid=admin@localhost --password=admin
```

Below is the error I am facing

```
ejabberdapi: error: user registration error for admin@localhost: Error 99: invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value
```

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: maybe I'm mixing concepts here, as I know nothing about Docker or ejabberd's Docker support.

But at least in main ejabberd, the "register" command accepts three arguments: user, host, password, see https://docs.ejabberd.im/developer/ejabberd-api/admin-api/#register

If that was your problem, then the error message doesn't help at all.

If I'm confused about how Docker works, then forget my comment.